# how to access value of radiobutton inside a label using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Consider we create radio buttons dynamically, so we can't access them by Id

```
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white" onclick="test();"> <input type="radio" value="abc" name="options"> this is a text </label>
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white" onclick="test();"> <input type="radio" value="dfdf" name="options"> this is a text </label>
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white" onclick="test();"> <input type="radio" value="reewr" name="options"> this is a text </label>
```

How can alert the value of radiobutton inside clicked label?

Comment: What if your application expands and you have more elements inside the label than just `<input type = 'radio' >` . Solutions having `children[0].value` will go wrong and you would have to rewrite the same piece of code.

Please tag my name if you want to notify me with any reply to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function test(event){
event.stopPropagation();

 console.log(event.currentTarget.firstElementChild.value);
 
}
```

```html
 <label class="btn btn-sm btn-white" onclick="test(event);"> <input type="radio" value="abc" name="options"> this is a text </label>
 <label class="btn btn-sm btn-white" onclick="test(event);"> <input type="radio" value="dfdf" name="options"> this is a text </label>
 <label class="btn btn-sm btn-white" onclick="test(event);"> <input type="radio" value="reewr" name="options"> this is a text </label>
```

Comment: It prints twice?

Comment: @vivek_23  i updated the fiddler..

https://jsfiddle.net/1qv5yakp/5/

since check box is inside the label, it will trigger twice.fixed the issue now

Comment: It still prints twice.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't really be using inline JS binding: use `addEventListener` instead. In the callback triggered by `addEventListener`, you will be able to get a reference to the element that triggers it via `event.target`.

`event.target` may refer to the `<label>` element or the `<input>` element, so we just have a simple if/else check to see which element the event is fired from, by checking `event.target.tagName`. If is an `<input>` element, we just get the element's `value` property.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
// Select the label elements in your DOM
// Note: You might have to adjust this!
var labelEls = document.querySelectorAll('label');

// Iterate through all selected `<label>` elements
Array.prototype.slice.call(labelEls).forEach(function(labelEl) {

  // Iteratively add the `click` event listener
  labelEl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    // If event is emitted by `<input>`
    if (event.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
      console.log('Value: ' + event.target.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <input type="radio" value="abc" name="options"> this is a text </label>
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <input type="radio" value="dfdf" name="options"> this is a text </label>
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <input type="radio" value="reewr" name="options"> this is a text </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

html

```
onclick=“test(this)”
```

js

```
function test(elmnt) {
     alert(elmnt.childNodes[1].value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `label.control` to reference HTML element associated with the label. Also avoid writing inline event handlers.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("label").forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    // this will refer to label
    console.log(this.control.value);
  })
});
```

```html
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <input type="radio" value="abc" name="options"> this is a text </label>
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <input type="radio" value="dfdf" name="options"> this is a text </label>
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <input type="radio" value="reewr" name="options"> this is a text </label>
```

Comment: It prints twice?

Comment: It does. Clicking label fires another onclick event for input element. Solving it depends on desired action when input itself is clicked. That is either check that it's not input element that was clicked, or attach event handler to input element.

Comment: In other words, it's `event propagation`.

Comment: @vivek_23 Event propagation normally doesn't run handlers twice. So it first fires with `event.target` referring to the clicked element, then it fires with `event.target` referring to associated input element, only fires once if you click that input element directly. It's also not cancelled by `event.stopPropagation();`.

Answer (score 0):

Identify each input with an id, then pass it to each test():

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test(e, id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    console.log(el.value);
  }

</script>

<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <input onclick="test(event,'id1')" type="radio" id="id1" value="abc" name="options"> this is a text </label>
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <input  onclick="test(event,'id2');" type="radio" id="id2" value="dfdf" name="options"> this is a text </label>
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <input onclick="test(event,'id3');" type="radio" id="id3" value="reewr" name="options"> this is a text </label>
```

Comment: Ok, this works as expected. Nothing against you, but did you read the question? It says `Consider we create radio buttons dynamically, so we can't access them by Id`. 

Also, `onclick()` is on the label in the question rather than the `<input>` element.

Comment: @vivek_23 I appreciate your efforts too. I haven't seen your answered before. But now that I see, it makes sense your 'efforts' to make 'shine' yours. SO community doesn't work like that. BTW Your answer is to 'heavy" for this simple question. Check mine

Comment: Question isn't as simple as it seems(I presume). The author of this question also has to show us more context for us to understand whether a simple solution is enough or it needs more revision to suit complex needs.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to add `classes` to a set of labels that you want to attach event listeners rather than attaching listeners based on tag names as there could many labels on your site webpage.

I have devised a solution using vanilla JS. Checks are done for `event propagation` (bubbling and capturing), type of the child element and tag name of the child element. This would keep the code safe even if we you add additional child elements to these labels when your application expands.

```js
var labels = document.getElementsByClassName('labels');

for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i) {
  labels[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'LABEL') {
      var kids = this.children;
      for (var j = 0; j < kids.length; ++j) {
        if (kids[j].type === 'radio' && kids[j].nodeName === 'INPUT') {
          console.log(kids[j].value);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white labels"> <input type="radio" value="abc" name="options"> this is a text </label>

<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white labels"> <input type="radio" value="dfdf" name="options"> this is a text </label>

<label class="btn btn-sm btn-white labels"> <input type="radio" value="reewr" name="options"> this is a text </label>
```